# How is Spring Boot aware of Heroku's DATABASE_URL config var?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, heroku

**Short story:**

How exactly does Spring Boot parse the `DATABASE_URL` config var? Setting an environment property with same name on my local PC has no effect. Which classes in Spring Boot library are involved? Full text search on `DATABASE_URL` returns nothing.

**Long story:**

I have recently deployed a simple Spring Boot + JPA application to Heroku. My heroku **was already configured with the Postgres add-on.**

During my first deployment I only wanted to confirm, that the application builds and starts correctly. To my surprise though, the application immediately connected to the Postgres database configured in Heroku's `DATABASE_URL` config var:

```
2018-11-30T09:28:51.054688+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-11-30 09:28:51.054  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

This leads me to the questions already posted above.

I am using Spring boot 2.1.0., a [simple app](https://github.com/ygor-sk/stackoverflow/tree/master/q123456789-spring-heroku-database_url) created by [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/), with `Web` + `JPA` + `H2` + `PostgreSQL`. `H2` is included, because:

- I want to run unit tests with embedded H2
- most of time, I want to run my application locally with embedded H2, but sometimes, I want to switch to Heroku's Postgres, so that I can verify some DB specific stuff (e.g. migrations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring is not aware of `DATABASE_URL` (as far as I know). But it does detect and automatically use `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`, which the Heroku Java buildpack sets at runtime.

You can read more about this env var in the Heroku docs on [Connecting to Relational Databases on Heroku with Java](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-spring_datasource_url-in-a-spring-boot-app)

Answer (score 2):

To be able to switch easily between h2 and heroku, one could have 2 configurations files

The h2 properties files named **application-h2.properties** :

```
spring.profiles.active=h2
spring.datasource.url= # H2 URL of the database.
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=# H2 JDBC driver. Auto-detected based on the URL by default.
spring.datasource.password= # Login password of the database.
spring.datasource.username= # Login username of the database.
```

Activated by setting the h2 profile to on when running the spring boot app:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=h2 myApplication.jar
```

The heroku properties files named **application-heroku.properties** :

```
spring.profiles.active=heroku
spring.datasource.url= # herokuURL of the database.
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=# herokuJDBC driver. Auto-detected based on the URL by default.
spring.datasource.password= # Login password of the database.
spring.datasource.username= # Login username of the database.
```

Activated by setting the heroku profile to on when running the spring boot app:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=heroku myApplication.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question, to amend the accepted answer with more details about environment properties set by Heroku.

Assuming, that your Heroku application contains environment variable:

- `DATABASE_URL` = `postgres://username:password@host:port/database`

Heroku will automatically provide following environment variables (which you can use e.g. in your favorite JDBC based SQL client):

- `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` = `jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?user=username&password=password&sslmode=require`
- `JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME` = `username`
- `JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD` = `password`

And additionally those, that get picked up by Spring Boot automatically (which you can use to modify your local Spring boot profile:

- `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME` = same as `JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME`
- `SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD` =  same as `JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD`
- `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` = same as `JDBC_DATABASE_URL`

I observed this, by using a simple REST endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping("/env")
public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> env() {
    return System.getenv();
}
```

Be careful, not to make the same mistake as I did: `DATABASE_URL` starts with `postgres`, while JDBC prefix for Postgres is `postgresql`. Using `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` with prefix `jdbc:postgres://` will lead to following error:

> Driver org.h2.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgres://....